# Intercept links outside of current domain and sub-domains

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, href, coldfusion-9

I am trying to make any link that is not internal show as a popup/new window. The data is user entered and pulled from a database. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you dynamically pulling links from the database and creating HTML links? Do you then just want those links to open in a new window when clicked on?

Comment: The user enters text and links using the entry form (ckeditor). If the user does not make it a link, it should not be clickable. The links are standard <a href=""></a> and need to open in a new window. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Links opening new windows are annoying, links opening popups are even more annoying. The middle mouse button is there for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery:

```
$(function () {

 $('a:not([href^="http://www.mysite"])').attr("target", "_new");

});
```

Comment: Note that you'll have to add additional :not([href='...']) values in there for other cases in which you'd like to keep then on the current page (such as for subdomains, or relative paths).

Comment: Is there a way to allow all subdomains? A wildcard?

Comment: Jake, Thank you for the reply. That didn't work, are there any other ways?

Comment: Here is what I have and it doesn't work.  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {

   $('a:not([href*="mysite.com"])').attr("rel", "gb_page_fs[]");

  });
 </script>

Comment: why are you using "rel", rather than "target"?  And what exactly "doesn't work"?  Are you getting a JS error?

Comment: Jake, sorry for that. I am using greybox as the popup, thus "rel" instead of target. The issue, that isn't shown in my comments, was with the domain I entered. I had and extra double quote at the end of my domain. Sorry for wasting any of your time! Your solution is great and I wish I was able to mark it as useful. Thank you again!